# How to config MULE Rmi?

Tags: java, soap, rmi, mule

I have a question about mule RMItransports

This is Example_RMITest.xml

```
<spring:bean name="jndiContext" factory-bean="jndiFactory" factory-method="create"/>

<rmi:connector name="rmi" jndiContext-ref="jndiContext" securityPolicy="rmi.policy"/> 

<rmi:endpoint name="hello" host="localhost" port="1099" object="HelloServer"
          method="hello" methodArgumentTypes="java.lang.String"/>
```

The exception is:

```
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: ClassNotFoundException: org.mule.transport.rmi.MuleRMIFactory
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:220)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.init(ApplicationWrapper.java:64)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:46)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentService.guardedDeploy(DeploymentService.java:398)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentService.start(DeploymentService.java:181)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.mule.module.reboot.MuleContainerWrapper.start(MuleContainerWrapper.java:56)
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager$12.run(WrapperManager.java:2788)
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name '_muleSimpleRegistryBootstrap' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/Ultra_ESB-1.0/lib/mule/mule-module-spring-config-3.3.0.jar!/default-mule-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Failed to lookup beans of type interface org.mule.api.transformer.Converter from the Spring registry (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:78)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:80)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:208)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Do you have the `mule-transport-rmi` jar in your classpath.. ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the `mule-transport-rmi` JAR in your classpath.